# Car goes in reverse when put in drive

Tags: transmission, chrysler-300

Car:2007 Chrysler 300 2.7

I went to start my car this morning, put it in drive, but it wouldn't go. Then I put it in reverse and it would drive back as well as neutral. So then I turned the car engine off and tried again - I put it in drive and it went in reverse. When I put in reverse it won't move. I went from low gear to drive and it went into drive.

Comment: What's the gear pattern in your car?  (Like `Park, Reverse, Drive, 3, L` or something)  Could you add some pictures of the shifter?  Something similar happened to me on a PT cruiser just before the shifter cable went out.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the shift linkage is loose or partially broken. Lift the car up and look at where the linkage connects to the transmission. I've seen where the brackets rot causing similar complaints.